# iOS Antialiasing with PNG on button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uistoryboard

I've got an issue with antialiasing on iOS. I have created a button and set its background to be a PNG image. On the iPad, it looks like this:

[image: ipad screenshot]

Whereas on the storyboard it looks like this:

[image: xcode storyboard]

And here are my settings in the attributes panel of xcode:

[image: xcode settings for button]

Comment: Maybe its too small to fit that container, try to give it @2x image

Comment: Have you created both the high res and low res versions of the image (high res with @2x at the end of the file name)?

Comment: It could also be that the image view is being resized, depending on your constraints. Since you have the content mode set to "scale to fill" the image may be getting resized.

Comment: I get the impression that the image is being resized - but I have two versions, and I've changed its mode to "center". Didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide the `2x` images in your resource too, so as to display them properly on retina device. Please make sure you have both version of images as mentioned & set just the normal-image name. The `2x` image is searched in the resource & will be taken automatically while execution.

`wizard-ceiling-desel-ipad.png`

`wizard-ceiling-desel-ipad@2x.png`

Its not just the name matters, you should also keep the size of images in 2x ratio. For example if normal image is `32x32` then make sure the `2x` image is of size `64x64`

Hope this helps.